# POST 400 bad request when uploading file to S3 using Lambda and API Gateway using static website

Tags: jquery, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have been following the tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IDoEERbTQm4) in order to upload files using a static S3 file in conjunction with API gateway and Lambda. I have followed all the steps as illustrated in the tutorial, however, when writing to the file I keep getting 'POST 400 bad request'.

I have ensured to specify datatype as JSON and JSON.stringify the data but the error seems to still persist. The code snippets are below but the site can be viewed on https://transcriberbucket1.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html

```
/*
Function called when the GET Object Event Button is triggered.
Images will be loaded automaticaly at the bottom div, For files, it will just show a null image icon(which is an error, if you have time fix it)
*/

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#UrlSignerBtnId").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://ze451btvv2.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/prod',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify({
                "BucketName": $('#BucketNameId').val(),
                "ObjectName": $('#ObjectNameId').val(),
                "methodType": $('#methodTypeId option:selected').attr('value'),
            }, ),
            dataType: "json",
            //beforeSend: function(){ $( '#loader' ).show();},
            success: function(res) {
                $("#urlTextId").html("Your <a href=" + res.PreSignedUrl + ">Pre-Signed Url</a> expires in " + res.ExpiresIn +" Seconds");
                $("#SignedUrlId").html("<img src='" + res.PreSignedUrl + "'>");
                $("#div-obj-holderId").show();
            },
            error: function(e) {
                $("#urlTextId").html("Unable to Retrieve Image, Check Object Key name.");
                $("#SignedUrlId").html("<i>"+ e.responseText + "</i>");
                $("#div-obj-holderId").show();
            },
            // complete: function() { $('#loader').hide(); }
        });
    });
});

/*
Function called when the Upload Object Event Button is triggered.
Gets the Pre-Signed Upload Url and Triggers the Upload Function
*/
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#ObjectUploadBtnId").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://ze451btvv2.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/prod',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify({
                "BucketName": $('#BucketNameId').val(),
                "methodType": $('#methodTypeId option:selected').attr('value'),
                "FileName": $('#FileNameId').val()
            }, ),
            dataType: "json",
            //beforeSend: function(){ $( '#loader' ).show();},
            success: function(res) {
                uploadFile(res, res.url);
            },
            error: function(e) {
                $("#urlTextId").html("Failed: Unable to Get Signed Upload Url" + e.responseText);
                $("#SignedUrlId").html("");
                $("#div-obj-holderId").show();
            },
            complete: function() {
                $('#loader').hide();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the time its the configuration that cause such problems.

Check `aws-region` used to create the lambda function and api-gateway are same or not.

Edit:
You might need to change the `aws-region:eu-cenral-1` to the region you deployed your lambda and api-gateway.
I ran the same code from the tutorial and i get the same issue of `POST 400 bad request`

But after changing it from  `eu-central-1` to `us-east-1`(region where is created the lambda and api-gateway) it fixed and both the features(upload and download) works.

```
    s3 = boto3.client('s3', region_name = 'eu-central-1',config=Config(signature_version='s3v4'))
```

to

```
    s3 = boto3.client('s3', region_name = 'us-east-1',config=Config(signature_version='s3v4'))
```

Comment: Thanks, Ruben. I have made the region changes as you pointed out and also changed the bucket name in the lambda function to my s3 bucket name `globalVars['BucketName']= "new-bucket-presign"`, however, I am still getting the error  'POST 400 bad request ' and 'POST net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET'. Here is the link to the site https://new-bucket-presign.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/index.html

Comment: check if the `globalVars['REGION_NAME']` is initialising the right values ?

Comment: I have set the `globalVars['REGION_NAME']`  it to "eu-central-1", since my bucket is located in eu-central-1 aswell as my lambda function and API gateway

Comment: i checked the code it harcoded the region, thats the reason it never picked up region you assinged to the globalVars['REGION_NAME'] 
`s3 = boto3.client('s3', region_name = 'us-east-1',config=Config(signature_version='s3v4'))` 
did you made the changes here as well ?

Comment: Yes, I have changed the code in the lambda function to `s3 = boto3.client('s3', region_name = 'eu-central-1',config=Config(signature_version='s3v4'))` but I am still unable to upload file. The region_name is set to 'eu-central-1' as my s3 bucket, lambda dunction and API gateway are located in Frankfurt eu-central-1

Comment: i just uploaded few images through your s3 website, I did not encountered any issue while uploading the images.

Comment: Here s the new link to the site (https://new-bucket-presign.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/index.html) . The new bucket name is 'new-bucket-presign'

Comment: lets chat here [link](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/238245/post-400-bad-request?tab=conversations)

Comment: Hi @BemTG, you can accept the answer if this help you in fixing your problem also add any othe workaround you use to handle it.